# How to display object which contains time

Tags: javascript

How to display time which comes from C# in this format: `{12:47:00}` in a label in  javascript?
When I display it in java script it displays as: `[object Object]`

html:

```
<label id="start_time"></label>
```

js:

```
$("#start_time").text(ret.Start_Time);
```

and `ret.Start_Time` comes from C# as `{12:47:00}` and `ret` is the list which holds the return time.

Comment: post your code, what did you try

Comment: html:
              <label id="start_time"></label>,js: $("#start_time").text(ret.Start_Time); and ret.Start_Time come from c# as {12:47:00} @Tom

Comment: Check the format, which format it is coming from C#

Comment: how can i do this ?? i need to display the time in java script as it return from c# @Akhlesh

Comment: time format come from c# @MH09

Comment: what is your "ret", textbox or ???

Comment: ret is the list which holds the return time @Tom

Comment: @AlaaKhalil Did you try `ret.Start_Time.toString()`?

Comment: first check the value in console(console.log(ret.Start_Time)). it will show you the actual object what it contains. What is the datatype in c# Datetime or timespan?

Answer (score 0):

use this `DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt")`   or look  [timespan.tostrig](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51.aspx)

they will give you string which are easily useable in javascript

Comment: the value already timespan i need to display it in javascript @Gyan Chandra Srivastava

Comment: first convert it to string then only you will able to use it

Comment: right now you are using timespan thats why you are facing problem convert it to string it will resolve your problem

Comment: when i make as you say there is an error :No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments @Gyan Chandra Srivastava

Comment: I think you are confused by DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt") and timespan.ToString()    as you are using timespan just point it as ToString()